# Помогите разобраться в задаче с go-tour

Tags: golang

На go-tour есть [задача-пример](https://go-tour-ru-ru.appspot.com/methods/23) rot13Reader. Самому мне не удалось ее решить, т.к. есть определенное недопонимание. В интернете я нашел решение данной задачи:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n,err = rot.r.Read(p)
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        if (p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] < 'N') || (p[i] >='a' && p[i] < 'n') {
            p[i] += 13
        } else if (p[i] > 'M' && p[i] <= 'Z') || (p[i] > 'm' && p[i] <= 'z'){
            p[i] -= 13
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Но после ознакомления с решением, заново прочитав материал по этой теме, ознакомившись с документацией я так и не пойму, почему этот код вообще работает. Вопросы следующие:

1. `io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)` <- В документации написано, что данный метод принимает `(dst Writer, src Reader)`, а в коде мы передаем ему адрес на func `rot13Reader`, где `io.Reader` это элемент структуры. Как это работает?
2. При выполнении программы метод `func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` вызывается, хотя в коде самого вызова нет. Почему?
3. Имеем параметр `p []byte` в который считывается информация `n,err = rot.r.Read(p)`. Далее происходят некие действия и программа выполняется. Идет копирование. Но т.к. `p` это не указатель, а копия он должен удалится после `return`, но по всей видимости это не происходит. Почему?

Comment: 1. io.Reader это не элемент структуры, а реализуемый интерфейс.upd : Если точнее - поле в виде интерфейса

Comment: 2. Вызов есть. Функция io.Copy/2 осуществляет его вот [здесь](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L400).

Comment: 3. Срез это ссылочный тип данных. Т.е. копия удалится, но на данные это не повлияет. Если вы не меняете размер, емкость или сам внутренний массив - вы можете изменить значение среза изнутри функции. Если меняете - значит надо возвращать и переприсваивать или передавать указатель.